# Optimize encrytion for limited memory (512 bit output)

Tags: algorithm, cryptography, encryption-asymmetric, elliptic-curve

I use products with unique numbers each.
I have to write code with both Asymmetric and Symmetric encryption algorithm for input data and store it in products.
The key of Symmetric is its unique number.
But now I want to know what is the maximum size of input data with some good Asymmetric algorithm that i can store it in my limited 512 bit memory.

For example some kind of ECC(Elliptic curve cryptography) get up to 16 character(128bit) input and generate 512 bit output.
Is there any good Asymmetric algorithm that can get more data bit (Ex.24 or 32 character) and generate just 512 bit?

I want chart comparison of encryption algorithms for input size and output size(max 512bit) at first . And key size , speed , complexity and... at next?

ThanX

Comment: Use asymmetric crypto only for keys (for symmetric) and hashes (of messages), not for actual data. Why your memory is limited to 512 bits, what chip is it?

Comment: User-Mem of UHF RFID tags.

Comment: *"For example some kind of ECC(Elliptic curve cryptography) get up to 16 character(128bit) input"* - No. That depends on specific crypto schemes and their implementation. Mathematically, it is possible to use "larger" curves. The issue is that these "short" curves provide good security *now* and are very efficient. Larger curves would take considerably longer.

Comment: Can you explain "crypto schemes" and "larger" please?

Comment: Do yuo see any ECC code example for tune the security and databits? Or link for it?